# spring-data-elasticsearch: how to combine and & or with CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a document with 4 fields, for simplicity sake A, B, C and D.
Now I'm trying to build a CriteriaQuery where

`((a = 1 AND b = 2 ) OR (a = 3 AND b = 43)) AND D = '4234234'` 
The basic flow using by creating

`new Criteria("a").is(1).and("b").is(2).and("d").is("4234234")`

Works fine.

But I'm having trouble getting it working fine with the OR aspect.

I thought

```
new Criteria("d").is("4234234").and(new Criteria("a").is(1).and("b").is(2)).or(new Criteria("a").is(1).and("b").is(2))
```

but thats leading to sharding erros.

Anyone that could point me in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples in the test code of Spring Data Elasticsearch, for example at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/main/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/client/elc/CriteriaQueryProcessorUnitTests.java#L167-L309

From one of the tests which creates ((John or Jack) and Miller) or ((Emma or Lucy) and Smith):

```java
        Criteria criteria = Criteria.or()
                .subCriteria(new Criteria("lastName").is("Miller")
                        .subCriteria(new Criteria().or("firstName").is("John").or("firstName").is("Jack")))
                .subCriteria(new Criteria("lastName").is("Smith")
                        .subCriteria(new Criteria().or("firstName").is("Emma").or("firstName").is("Lucy")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 subcriteria

(a = 1 AND b = 2 ):

```
Criteria subcriteria_1_2 = new Criteria("a").is("1").and("b").is("2" );
```

(a = 3 AND b = 43)

```
Criteria subcriteria_3_43 = new Criteria("a").is("3").and("b").is("43");
```

Merged (a = 1 AND b = 2 ) OR (a = 3 AND b = 43)

```
Criteria subcriteria_1_2_3_43 = new Criteria().or().subCriteria(subcriteria_1_2).subCriteria(subcriteria_3_43);
```

Final connect with AND D = '4234234'

```
Criteria finalCriteria = new Criteria("d").is("4234234").subCriteria(subcriteria_1_2_3_43);
```

This construction will generate JSON (very simplified)

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "4234234",
          "fields" : [
            "d"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "bool" : {
          "should" : [
            {
              "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                  {
                    "query_string" : {
                      "query" : "1",
                      "fields" : [
                        "a"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "query_string" : {
                      "query" : "2",
                      "fields" : [
                        "b"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
                "boost" : 1.0
              }
            },
            {
              "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                  {
                    "query_string" : {
                      "query" : "3",
                      "fields" : [
                        "a"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "query_string" : {
                      "query" : "43",
                      "fields" : [
                        "b"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
                "boost" : 1.0
              }
            }
          ],
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

I recommend to not mix and() with or() in one chain. Use subcriteria. If you need to use subcriteria in one chain with field check, always put subcriteria to the end of chain. For example this construction will not work (at final, subcriteria will be erased)

```
new Criteria("test").is("test_value").subCriteria(subcriteria_1_2_3_43).and("d").is("4234234");
```

But if you put subcriteria to the end of chain it will work

```
new Criteria("test").is("test_value").and("d").is("4234234").subCriteria(subcriteria_1_2_3_43);
```

This is solution which i used in my own project